# converting array of paths to array of unique paths

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of paths that i want to convert to an array of unique paths. Below is my attempt and i know there is a recursive call somewhere in function returnPath but don't know exactly how to implement that.

```js
var paths = [{
  out: "KFvEbaKPDC|o|0",
  in: "M7gtymFAo4|i|0"
}, {
  out: "KFvEbaKPDC|o|0",
  in: "53s1L4YLpo|i|0"
}, {
  out: "M7gtymFAo4|o|0",
  in: "DEa78KAyDf|i|0"
}, {
  out: "53s1L4YLpo|o|0",
  in: "R6hUSNn5T5|i|0"
}]

function chainPaths(paths) {
  let localCopy = paths;
  const chainPaths = [];
  localCopy = localCopy.filter((item) => {
    if (item.out.split('|')[0] === 'KFvEbaKPDC') {
      return item;
    }
  })
  console.log(localCopy);
  localCopy.forEach((c) => {
    chainPaths.push(returnUniquePath(c));
  })
}

function returnUniquePath(c) {
  const arr = [];
  arr.push(c.out);
  arr.push(c.in);
  //recursive call here may be??
  return arr;
}

chainPaths(paths)
```

i am hoping to end up with an array that has unique paths like below

```
[[
  "KFvEbaKPDC|o|0",
  "M7gtymFAo4|i|0"
  "M7gtymFAo4|o|0",
  "DEa78KAyDf|i|0"
],[
  "KFvEbaKPDC|o|0",
  "53s1L4YLpo|i|0"
  "53s1L4YLpo|o|0",
  "R6hUSNn5T5|i|0"
]]
```

lets imagine 'KFvEbaKPDC' to be a parent node, this parent has output path, denoted by 'o' as in KFvEbaKPDC|o|0, to two children 'M7gtymFAo4' and '53s1L4YLpo' on their inputs denoted by 'i' and each child i.e. M7gtymFAo4' and '53s1L4YLpo' has an output path to another node. Hope that makes sense.

one can visualize unique paths as below

```
KFvEbaKPDC|o|0 -> M7gtymFAo4|i|0 -> M7gtymFAo4|o|0 -> DEa78KAyDf|i|0
KFvEbaKPDC|o|0 -> 53s1L4YLpo|i|0 -> 53s1L4YLpo|o|0 -> R6hUSNn5T5|i|0
```

I was able to treeify the paths array and then was able to traverse unique paths like

```
KFvEbaKPDC -> M7gtymFAo4 -> DEa78KAyDf
```

but that solution lacked information about inputs, outputs and indices

Comment: I almost understand your need, I just don't get the desired result, why you want two objects inside the array and/or what is the filters that made each path be included in each object?

Comment: The end result doesn't make sense.

Comment: So you want the output to be an invalid JavaScript object, why don't you just try `return undefined.undefined`? That would be much simpler.

Comment: lets imagine 'KFvEbaKPDC' to be a parent node, this parent has output path, denoted by 'o' in KFvEbaKPDC|o|0, to two children  'M7gtymFAo4' and '53s1L4YLpo'  on their inputs denoted by 'i' and each child i.e. M7gtymFAo4' and '53s1L4YLpo' has an output path to another node.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: If you are looking at a tree like structure, then why not create a tree? Why this playing around with `i` and `o`? What do you hope the benefit will be in the end?

Comment: I agree with @Icepickle — your data representation is most of the problem here. If you can change that to something more useful like an adjacency list, everything will be much easier.

Comment: I am a bit confused here, OP is using `paths` which usually is indicative of a graph problem, however the problem itself really sounds like a good solution for a tree. Can you clarify your end goal @Adi?

Comment: @Icepickle: I am afraid the inputs and outputs are kindof essential to indicate the flow between nodes. I was able to treeify the paths array and then was able to traverse unique paths like  KFvEbaKPDC -> M7gtymFAo4 -> DEa78KAyDf but that solution lacked information about inputs, outputs and indices

Comment: @Adi, I don't see why, a tree could have all sort of custom properties where you could add this information to. Otoh, I also don't see what you wish to accomplish with the end result or why a tree wouldn't be helpful in your scenario...

Comment: @Icepickle: Thanks for the suggestion, having custom properties to accommodate additional information sounds good.